# WPF DataGrid binding difficulties

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

This is the class:

```
public class TrainingData
{
    public string Training { get; set; }  
}
```

And this is the rest of the code in MainWindow:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:/excel.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
List <TrainingData> tData= new List <TrainingData>();

int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
//int k = 0; 

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    tData.Add(new TrainingData() { Training = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString() });
    //MessageBox.Show(tData[k].Training); 
    //k++;
}

Prikaz.ItemsSource = tData;
```

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="Prikaz" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>`
```

So, Prikaz is my DataGrid. tData is List of TrainingData objects. If I uncomment these three lines I can test if I have imported information from excel file correctly, and yes, that works just fine.

So why am I getting empty DataGrid? It has right number of rows and only one column, that's ok, but there are no data in it. I used this line:  `Prikaz.ItemsSource = tData;` to bind my objects list and DataGrid. Training is declared public so it should be present in DataGrid. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the Xaml for the grid

Comment: Do you get the data if you set AutoGeneratedColumns="True" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the column path to the property Training.

The syntax is something like this but that is just from memory. 
Text need to be bound to the path Training

Use [DataGridTextColumn Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn.aspx):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Training}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

or

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Path=Training}/>
```

Comment: This line solved the problem:`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Path=Training}/>`Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have specified the `ItemsSource` property in code, you would also need to provide the binding to the columns in your `DataGrid` connecting to the ItemsSource object with its property, like this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Path=Training}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You would additionally also want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your `TrainingData` class and also instead of using collection `List<TrainingData>` would be better to use `ObservableCollection<TrainingData>` collection object. This [MSDN article](http://in.search.yahoo.com/r/_ylt=A8pWBidoqNxPYiMAFZ27HAx.;_ylu=X3oDMTFhNWw1bm82BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2luMl9pbnRsBHZ0aWQDUkNGSU4wMl83NA--/SIG=12920tcqu/EXP=1339889896/%2a%2ahttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) gives `DataBinding` overview and why you would want to use above interfaces in your custom class.